# Is there a way to delete firebase database parent node on button click?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am looking for a way to delete an entire node from firebase database

I managed to display all items in a recyclerview.
Now I want to delete those items on a button click.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided your database structure or Code so the only code i can provide you.

```
deletebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DatabaseReference nodeKeyRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("node_name").child(nodekey);
        nodeKeyRef.removeValue();
    }
});
```